getting out of memory error when running docker kafka
I am getting out of memory error (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory) when trying to run kafka locally using docker compose below. Tried different env properties still getting error when processing big xml message.
The Spring Boot 2.X app connects to kafka for consuming big xml message.
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_SOCKET_REQUEST_MAX_BYTES: 400000000
      KAFKA_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS: 3000000
      KAFKA_MAX_POLL_RECORDS: 1
      KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx1g -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic:1:1"

Appreciate any help/suggestions

What different properties have you tried? Did you change the heap size under KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS?

the post has all that i have tried so far

Firstly, Kafka no longer requires Zookeeper...
Increase the broker Xmx value and/or use the official apache/kafka-native Docker image, which is using GraalVM and has a lower memory overhead than OpenJDK (the wurstmeister image is no longer maintained)
